# find a quadratic equation that : $\alpha^2+\beta^2-\alpha\beta=7$ and $(\alpha+2)(\beta+2)=20$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hi please help me solving this puzzle
$\alpha$ $\beta$ are roots of an quadratic equation.
I want to create an equation using this rules about Its roots:
$$\alpha^2+\beta^2-\alpha\beta=7$$
$$(\alpha+2)(\beta+2)=20$$
Actualy the puzzle has given us some information about root and we must find and write the quadratic aquation.
I know badical rules about quadratic equations like delta.

Comment: $\alpha = 2$, $\beta = 3$? Or their other permutation?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$20=4+(\alpha+\beta)+2(\alpha\beta)\iff\alpha\beta=?$$

$$7=(\alpha+\beta)^2-3\alpha\beta\iff\alpha\beta=?$$

Compare the two values of $\alpha\beta$ to find a Quadratic equation in $\alpha+\beta$

Use the second equation to find $\alpha\beta$

Answer (score 1):

Given $\alpha^2+\beta^2-\alpha\beta=7$ and $(\alpha+2)(\beta+2)=20$

From the above two equations and by trail and error method we can easily say that $2,3$ are the roots.

So, the quadratic equation is $(x-2)(x-3)=0$
$$x^2-5x+6=0$$